# Why is the accusative not used in Judges 5:23?

Tags: vulgata, accusative

This verse [reads](http://www.drbo.org/x/d?b=lvb&bk=7&ch=5&l=23-#x):

> Maledicite **terrae** Meroz, dixit angelus Domini : maledicite **habitatoribus** ejus, quia non venerunt ad auxilium Domini, in adjutorium fortissimorum ejus.

The context is that of [Deborah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deborah) telling a story to the people of Israel through a song/canticle.

*Maledicite* is an active present plural imperative, something like "You, curse" (you being plural) (the imperative *maldigan*, in Spanish). I would have expected the accompanying nouns to be in the accusative (*terram*, *habitatores*), given that they are, as far as I can see, the direct object of the verb *maledicere*. However, they seem to be taking the dative. I know there are some verbs that do take the dative by definition (e.g. *servire*, as in one serves **to** someone), but as far as Wiktionary and L&S state, *maledicere* is not one of them.

What's the issue? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the word comes from *male dico*, it traditionally took the dative for the same reason that *dico* takes it. The dative expresses to whom something is spoken or for whom the speech is beneficial (or, in this case, harmful).

According to [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=Maledicite#lexicon), the dative was normally used in the classical period, but later the accusative came into usage:

> mălĕdīco (or separately, **mălĕ dīco** ;
>
> I.“rarely in reverse order: qui bonis dicunt male,” Plaut. Bacch. 1,
>   2, 10; cf. id. Trin. 4, 2, 79), xi. ctum, 3, v. n. and a. [male-dico],
>   to speak ill of, to abuse, revile, slander, asperse; constr. absol.,
>   or with a **dat. (so class.)** or **acc. (post-Aug.)**. *(emphasis added)*